# Problem with ADC configuration - atmega328p

Tags: adc, interrupts, atmega328p

What's up folks?

I've been developing a project using atmega328p and avr-gcc.
Recently, I've tried to configure the ADC to single sample.
The codes below show my main.c, ADC.c and ADC.h

```
//main.c

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include "drivers/ADC.h"

volatile int timer_counter = 0; //value of timer_counter
volatile uint8_t converteu;

int main (void){
        CLKPR = (1<<CLKPCE); // enabling bit writing in clock divider
        CLKPR = 2; //clock divider = 4, from 8 MHz to 2 MHZ
        configure_ADC(); // clock = 62.5 KHz, AREF = AVCC, single sample

        DDRB = 7; // PB0, PB1, PB2 as output

        while(1){
           sei();
           set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_IDLE);
           sleep_mode();
        }
}
```

```
//ADC.c

#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(ADC_vect){
        PORTB ^= 2;      
}

void configure_ADC(){

        ADMUX |= (1<<REFS0); //short circuiting AVCC with AREF, ADC0 is the port enable to be read


        ADMUX &= ~((1<<MUX0)+(1<<MUX1)+(1<<MUX2)+(1<<MUX3)); //selecting ADC0
        ADCSRA |= (1<<ADEN); //ADC enable
        ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS2) + (1<<ADPS0); // AVCC as reference

        ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIE); //enabling interruption
        PRR &= ~PRADC; // no low power on ADC
}
```

```
//ADC.h
void configure_ADC();
```

These code should do nothing, just configure ADC to run in single sample.
However when I run it in my microcontroller, without activating ADSC (bit that starts a conversion), the PORTB 2 is activated. The only place that enables PORTB 2 is in the ADC's ISR.

The ISR is executed without activating the ADSC bit.

What's happening with this code?

Comment: What does **PORTB gets activated** mean?

Comment: _"These code should do nothing, just configure ADC to run in single sample."_ - but the comment says "auto triggering enabled, trigger_event = free running"!

Comment: The free running comment is a past configuration that I tried. I forgot to erase it. I will edit the question.

Comment: @User323693 PORTB gets activated means that a logic one is written on the pin.

Comment: What is teh default state of the pin? If you comment that port B Part in ADC ISR wil it still behave the same?

Comment: @User323693 no, it doesn't behave the same way. If I comment the PORTB in ADC ISR, the port rely on 0 logical level

Comment: Where are you configuring the port B as output? Are thee any pull-ups enabled ?

Comment: @User323693 in main.c I configured PORTB as output. Does pull-up configuration matter if the port is setted as an output? when I comment the **ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIE);**, in adc.c, the pin's state remains 0. It seems to me that the adc's isr has been executed by **configure_ADC** regardlees the ADSC value.

Comment: When will the ADC interrupt gets fired? When is it intended to trigger

Comment: @User323693 I developed a complete code, that is triggered by some conditions, however, when I started debugging it I noticed that the ISR is executed before triggered. Now, I just wanna understand why this is happening. Later, when this problem will have solved, I can explain better all the algorithm.

Comment: @AndréMachoski I have a doubt that *whatever condition which will cause the output to trigger* is already set ..so soon after enabling the interrupt, it is getting triggered.. can you check this.. or make sure that the input to the ADCis at a state which can not trigger interrupt

Comment: @User323693 I tried to get rid of the sleep mode, and the problem disappears. I just don't understand how sleep mode affects the ADC interruption.

Comment: Can you show the related hardware if possible? Sleep modes.. will the ADC be running in sleep mode or it will be disabled?

Comment: According to the datasheet, in Idle mode the ADC will be running. What do you mean by related hardware, schematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I discovered the reason for the ISR being requested without changes in ADSC.

The Idle mode's description, in the datasheet, states:

" If the ADC is enabled, a conversion starts automatically when this mode is entered."

The idle mode is triggering the ADC.

Comment: That's good. you seem to have found the solution